# Why is there no Session on Hub OnConnected / OnDisconnected?

Tags: c#, .net, session, signalr, signalr-hub

When I override `OnConnected` / `OnDisconnected` and then looking for a Session with `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null.

I was assuming that a Session would have been already created by this time. Do I miss something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SignalR doesn't use Session on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854663/signalr-doesnt-use-session-on-server)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have session enabled on your app

reading through [HtpContext.Current.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it looks like you need to verify if

> "You cannot set or get a session-state value if session state is not enabled. To configure session-state settings for an application, set the mode attribute of the sessionState element in the Web.config file. When session state is enabled and you request a value from a session-state variable that does not exist, null is returned".

If you are thinking that signalR should have enabled session state for you then no it will not [confirmed by @dfowler] at [Another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854663/signalr-doesnt-use-session-on-server)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the GetHttpContext?

```
var ctx = Context.Request.GetHttpContext();
```

Comment: GetHttpContext does not exist, can you send me all the using statements

Answer (score 0):

You could get the sessionID directly from the cookie in OnConnected / OnDisconnected:

`public override Task OnConnected() {
     var sessionId = Context.RequestCookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value;
}`

Now having the sessionID string, you could lookup the session from a custom singleton dictionary, populated when each session is created - for example in Global.asax like this:

`void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalSessions[context.Session.SessionID] = context.Session;
}`

Of course this only works if the web application is on a single server.