# How to pass data to Signalr hub class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have some global data that stored in session["Gdata"] so that I can access these information any time I want. However, I can't access session["Gdata"] in signalr hub class.
Is there any way to access session in hub class ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522477/no-access-to-the-session-information-through-signalr-hub-is-my-design-is-wrong , also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854663/signalr-doesnt-use-session-on-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use session in Signalr hub class, see this link

[No access to the Session information through SignalR Hub. Is my design is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522477/no-access-to-the-session-information-through-signalr-hub-is-my-design-is-wrong)

There are some solutions to your problem. You can use Standard ASP.NET security to store your global information.

You can store the data you want using this code

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("string contain your data", false);
```

and you can retrieve your data using this code

```
string GlobalData = Context.User.Identity.Name;
```